# wait to load angularjs directive template

Tags: angularjs

What I am trying to do is postpone loading the angular js template for a directive until I really need it. I might not even need it at all. Is there a way that I can maybe only load the  template for a directive if I need it. Would a service be the way to do this? My application already loads a lot of directive templates and I would like to avoid loading too much stuff unless I need it. The exact problem at hand is the loading of a template for a login form. If the user clicks on a button and he/she is not logged in I want to slideOpen (using jQuery) a login form.

Comment: It can be done, but it requires a bit of work. Directive templates are usually *really* small and I can't imagine a log-in form being anything but tiny. Why are you looking to load this asynchronously?

Comment: Just wanted to know if there was a good way of doing it. I agree the login form is small but I was thinking that if it was something that was easy to do I would I have a go at it. I should add that I don't shy from the difficult things so if there is a way of doing this I would like to know because it would add to my general understanding of angular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases, there is no value to dynamically loading static directive templates. They are so small that it just doesn't make sense to do it. But, it is possible.  However, most of the time, this strategy is used for dynamic templates.

It requires `$http` to fetch the template and `$compile` to wire it into AngularJS.

```js
app.directive('testDirective', function($http,$compile) {
  return {
    scope: { show: '&' },
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
      var tpl,
          url = 'testDirective.tpl.html';

      scope.$watch( 'show()', function (show) {
        if ( show ) {
          showTheDirective();
        }
      });

      function showTheDirective () {
        if ( !tpl ) {
          $http.get( url ).then( function ( response ) {
            tpl = $compile( response.data )( scope );
            element.append(tpl);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IWHGqsSAI8ZLKlVfu12o?p=preview) demonstrating that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try and `ng-if` on the directive.

```
<your-directive ng-if='userLoggedIn'></your-directive>
```

and in your controller

```
app.controller('yourCtrl', function($scope, service){
    $scope.dataHasLoaded = false;

    service.yourUserLoginFuntion(params).then(function (data) {
         //your login api
         $scope.userLoggedIn = true
    });
});
```

where scope variable `userLoggedIn`  is true only when you require the directive to load.