# Handle ng-click event from code included with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I've created document header with few buttons and the header is included from some of my views using `ng-include`.
Each view has its own controller and each button has on-click event.
What is the best practice to handle such a case, in order to prevent code replication?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you make a controller for that template you are ng-including and use that controller to handle any click events specific to that template?

Comment: If you are reusing and making any DOM manipulation, i would suggest you write a directive, i would use ng-include in cases where the content is mostly static. follow this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171893/angularjs-nginclude-vs-directive

Answer (score 1):

You could move that part of code to directive so that placing only directive element there would be enough, Code will be reuse as you want.

**Html**

```
<my-directive template-url="abc.html" click-function="refreshData()"></my-directive>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       templateUrl: function(ele, attr){
           return attr.templateUrl
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.find('button').on('click', function(){
              scope.$apply(function(){
                  scope.$eval(attrs.clickFunction())
              });
          })
       }

   }
})
```

Above directive you could pass your `templateUrl` name in attribute which would do the work of `ng-include` & for click event you need to pass click event reference on `clickFunction` attribute. That will call on click of button.