# Whats the difference between ng-include and directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I'm currently learning AngularJS and I dont understand, whats the difference between `ng-include` and a `directive`.

Now I'm using `ng-include` just for readability on my app.

When is best practice to use `ng-include` and when to make a directive?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171893/angularjs-nginclude-vs-directive

Comment: Sorry, I didint found that, thanks!