# Prevent directive's templateUrl from being downloaded at page load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, lazy-loading

So I have a directive that I'm setting up like this:

```
<div my-directive ng-if="conditionThatIsInitiallyFalse"></div>
```

```
angular.module('myModule', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'my-directive-template.html'
  };
});
```

The problem is that, although `myDirective`'s code is correctly not being executed due to the `ng-if`, I can see in the dev tool's network tab that there is a request being made for the corresponding `my-directive-template.html`. Even doing something like this won't help:

```
<div ng-if="conditionThatIsInitiallyFalse">
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to prevent angular from loading the directive's template until the directive is actually used.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I just realised that this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904139/wait-to-load-angularjs-directive-template). Mods please do your thing ;)

Comment: Rather than use the `templateUrl` directive property, an alternative is to fetch and compile a template in `link` function, then adding it to the DOM as necessary. This technique is also used by [`ng-include`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js) (cf. Around line 218). Pretty certain it won't fetch your template before the directive is _used_.

Comment: Add the HTML file to the $templateCache. It's downloaded once and cached on the client - all of which is transparent to the directive

Comment: possible duplicate of [wait to load angularjs directive template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904139/wait-to-load-angularjs-directive-template)